# Sum directory sizes

Tags: directory, disk-usage

I have a folder with multiple .NET projects, let's call the parent directory `projects`. Each .NET project has a `bin` folder with the binaries built for that project. Now I want to get the sum of the sizes of the files in all of these folders.

So far, I can get a list of each `bin` directory with

```
du -h | grep 'bin$'
```

This gives the size of each `bin` along with the path to that directory.

How do I sum these up? Can I do it with just `du` or do I need to pipe to some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using `-h` since the units change depending on the size of the directory. Using `-b` gives sizes in bytes, which you can then convert to whatever you need. This being Linux, you have multiple options.

```
du -b | awk '/bin$/{print $1'} | paste -sd+ - | bc

du -b | awk '/bin$/{Total=Total+$1} END {print "Total "Total" bytes"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use (`-s`) to get a summarized value for each directory (to not print subdirectories) and (`-c`) for a grand total.
If there are not too many projects, pass each directory as argument, e.g.:

```
$ du -hsc projects/projectone/bin projects/projecttwo/bin
30M projects/projectone/bin
2.0M    projects/projecttwo/bin
32M total
```

If there are many directories with different structures, use `find` and `du`:

```
$ find projects -type d -name bin -exec du -hsc {} +
```

---

If you only need the total value, pipe the command to `awk` to print the first field of the last line:

```
... | awk 'END{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: To clarify, I only want the bin directories and no others. There are hundreds of projects, so too many to list by hand.

Comment: Have you tried the `find` command or does it exceed ARG_MAX?

Comment: Looks like your `find` suggestion will work.